# Admin routing, http://website.com/admin won't go to posts/admin_index

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, admin

I have admin routing enabled. How can I set routing, to make http://website.com/admin go to posts/admin_index?

I've got this:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I get this error (when going to http://website.com/admin):

```
Missing Controller

Error: Controller could not be found.

Error: Create the class Controller below in file: app/controllers/controller.php

<?php
class Controller extends AppController {

    var $name = '';
}
?>
```

Comment: if you try to reset the values of the Router::connect, does the error still showing up? this is weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a route with:

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

The default route `'/'` does not match the URL `'/admin'`, admin routing enabled or not.